# How to pass new messages to the thread function on run time?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

In `pthread_create` I can specify one message, then on run time I may get new messages that need to be passed to the thread for printing.

One way may be to create a global vector, and keep on adding messages to it. The thread will fetch that vector and scan it for new messages.
But in this way n vectors will have to be created for n threads!
Or one structure with threadid, message, and print status.

What are the possible practical ways out?

### EDIT 1:

Is the following design fine or needs some improvements?

*The following code will be written in a normal function which will be called by main().*

- Check if the thread (responsible for grabbing that message) is already there.

  - If yes,  Push the message in that thread's queue, wake up the thread with (pthread_cond_signal()).
  - If no, create the thread, create its queue, push the message in that queue.
- When the thread finishes reading all the messages in its queue, let it to sleep with (pthread_cond_wait()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google 'pthreads producer consumer queue'. You should not need to scan for new entries - the producer/s signal the consumer thread that new entries are available.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a global queue I would use a linked list, not a vector, and lock it with a mutex otherwise your going to get race conditions.

Comment: Yeah locking will be necessary. thanks. Why a link list not a vector?

Comment: A linked list is much faster to add/remove elements from as realloc/memmove's are not required as the list grows/shrinks, your just updating pointers.

Comment: @Geofferey Okay, thanks. well, that's going to be a new question. :) Also, why a mutex on the global queue? The threads will read their id's in the queue and act accordingly, they won't delete a random message! Am I wrong?

Comment: If one thread is removing an item from the queue while a thread is adding an item, the internals of the list will get screwed up, things such as first/last element, and list size. Also, if you don't want to implement all the symantecs of a queue yourself, have a look at beanstalkd as an external queue.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Also, that adding thread can be the main() function itself? main() is also considered to a thread?

Comment: No problems, the main process can be used to populate the queue, but remember to reap your threads at application termination (pthread_wait) or start them un-parented (cant remember the exact term)

Comment: The main process is a process that owns the threads, it can act independent of the threads just like an extra running thread and still shares the same address space as its children.

Comment: So, you mean even if I use main() process to add the data to the global queue, and the threads will just have to delete the data, will the race condition still occur?

Comment: @Anisha: "The threads will read their id's in the queue and act accordingly".  If work items will be assigned to a particular thread, then you should probably consider giving each thread its own queue.  Note that you'd still want each queue protected by a mutex (or use a proper lock-free queue) so that the data structure doesn't get corrupted if an add occurs concurrently with a remove.

Comment: @MichaelBurr `If work items will be assigned to a particular thread, then you should probably consider giving each thread its own queue` if mutex have to be used in any case then why a separate queue?

Comment: @Anisha: a couple reasons - 1) threads won't have to search for its work items, and 2) there will likely be less contention on the queues: if a work item is being placed on Thread A's queue, Thread B won't have to block to pull an item off if its queue - the mutex on its queue won't be held.

Answer (score 0):

Make global vector as pthread specific data, so each thread will have it own copy of the data. You do not need to create N number of variables.